# unable to add column in a resetted datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, datatables, duplicates

I have this problem, i have an initialization script that set up all the objects that i need to work with my data. I created a DataTable with one column and fill it with a certain amount of row.
I use another script to copy my data from a sql select into datatable with this:

```
Mtriggersql = value;
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select [Weight] from [dbo].[L01_BlockData] where [ID_PressStack] = 1 order by [ID_Block] asc";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);

DrawGrid(dt);
ldtbl = dt;
```

Where my ldtbl is a public global datatable that i have declared on top of the script.

Then if certain condition are met i need to reinitialize my objects and also my datatable so i do this again:

```
if (ldtbl.Columns.Count > 0) ldtbl.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Values";
ldtbl.Clear();
ldtbl.Reset();
ldtbl.Dispose();
lCol.Dispose();
lCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int16");
lCol.ColumnName = "Values";
ldtbl.Columns.Add(lCol);
DataRow lRow = ldtbl.NewRow();
for (int i = 0; i < BlockGridWidth * BlockGridHeight; i++)
{
    lRow = ldtbl.NewRow();
    lRow["Values"] = -1;
    ldtbl.Rows.Add(lRow);
}
```

The problem is that when i try to add the column (even tho the datatable has been resetted) there is an exception that say :

> "column "Values" already belongs to this datatable"

In debug mode when i check the datatable right before the column is added, the datatable is empty so i don't know why there is this error.

Hope to find some solutions and thanks you in advance

Comment: Are you 100% sure the error is not coming from the line … `if (ldtbl.Columns.Count > 0) ldtbl.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Values";` … ? … I am just saying that when the code executes the line… `ldtbl.Reset();` … this will remove ALL the columns in the table so adding a column named “Values” after this, should NOT throw that error and in my small tests, this indeed worked as expected. However, `IF` the table `ldtbl` ALREADY has a column named “Values” before this code is called… then you WILL get the error you describe on the line of code I pointed to previously.

Comment: I suggest you test this by adding an additional check to see if `ldtbl` ALREADY has a column named `Values` BEFORE the code attempts to set column zero’s `ColumnName` property. In addition… this check and renaming of the column appears superfluous… In other words, the first `if` statement is a wasted effort since two lines of code later the “renamed” column is deleted when `ldtbl.Reset();` is executed… ? …

Comment: im sure that the scripts give me an error on the Columns.Add() line, i change the column name because at first i was thinking about the column that my query gives back has the column name specified in the query so: [Weight] and given that the error pop-up only when i make that query i have done that, but probably is useless.
i was thinking also that maybe the problem is that i have a datatable called ldtbl and i equal to my other datatable dt so ldtbl=dt but the two datatable have different column name.

Comment: i have tried to check if a column called "Values" exist after the sql result, and the only column that exist is the column "Weight" from the sql query, and then i uselessly rename the column name but also after doing that i reset the table and try to add the column with no success.

Comment: Well… there must be something else going on that you are not showing… in my small tests, using your posted code, I never got the error you describe. I had other issues with the `ldtbl.Reset();` … however these issues were remedied by simply creating a new `DataTable` like… `ldtbl = new DataTable();` … Is there some reason you do not create a new `DataTable` as opposed to calling the tables `”Clear” and “Reset” methods?